# Problems adding a picture in checkbox in checkedchanged event

Tags: vb.net

Good morning everyone.

I´m trying to put an image in a checkbox when its status changes (checkedchanged event) and then, make a screenshot with this checkbox changed status, but, when event is fired, and screenshot is done, picture does not appear before next code executes. 
I´m wondering if is there any way to make it like vb after update event.
Does anyone know how can I make it?
Thanks!!

My code:

```
Private Sub CheckBox_accept_terms_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles CheckBox_accept_terms.CheckedChanged

Try
    If CheckBox_accept_terms.Checked Then

        CheckBox_accept_terms.Image = My.Resources.cancelar

        If moveTmpPic_finalPic() Then
            If agreement_screenshot() Then
                If generate_xml() Then
                    If generate_zip() Then
                        send_email_agreement = False
                        Common_functions.savedCapture = New Saved_capture_form
                        Common_functions.savedCapture.Show()
                        Me.Close()
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        End If
    End If

Catch

End Try

End Sub
```

I also tried:

```
Private Sub CheckBox_accept_terms_BackgroundImageChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles CheckBox_accept_terms.BackgroundImageChanged

Try
    If CheckBox_accept_terms.Checked Then

        If moveTmpPic_finalPic() Then
            If agreement_screenshot() Then
                If generate_xml() Then
                    If generate_zip() Then
                        send_email_agreement = False
                        Common_functions.savedCapture = New Saved_capture_form
                        Common_functions.savedCapture.Show()
                        Me.Close()
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        End If
    End If

Catch

End Try

End Sub

Private Sub CheckBox_accept_terms_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles CheckBox_accept_terms.CheckedChanged

    CheckBox_accept_terms.BackgroundImage = My.Resources.cancelar

End Sub
```

Comment: Are you sure that your code gets to that point? Set a breakpoint and see. Using Checkbox.BackgroundImage = My.Resources.XXXX works for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add an `Update()` call, or a `Refresh()` call, to see if that helps.

Try:

```
Private Sub CheckBox1_CheckedChanged(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles CheckBox1.CheckedChanged
    CheckBox1.BackgroundImage = My.Resources.garbage

    CheckBox1.Update()
    'or use refresh
    CheckBox1.Refresh()
End Sub
```

Update makes the control "update", and should force show your image.

If your problem is that the image is not displaying properly, it may be the layout of your background image. Stretch will make the image fit into the size of your control (rather than stay full-size).

```
        CheckBox1.BackgroundImageLayout = ImageLayout.Stretch
```

Comment: That´s just what I was looking for. Tahks a lot!!